Why MATLAB imwarp isn't working for cylindrical projection?
I am trying to find the cylindrical projection of an image using the cylindrical projection equations. After finding the warpped values for the X and Y coordinates, I am trying to use the inbuilt MATLAB imwarp function to project the image onto the new coordinates, so that I can use the interpolation for smooth image. However, I get a different warpped image. Here is the output what I am getting:

What I expect the image to be:

Below is the cylindrical projection code:
clc; close all; clear;

% Inputs
fileName = 'checker.jpg';

% Focal lengths
fx = 50;
fy = 50;

% Read image
image = (imread(fileName));

% Get image size
[ydim, xdim, bypixs] = size(image);

% Camera intrinsics
K = [fx, 0, xdim/2; 0, fy, ydim/2; 0, 0, 1];

% Distortion coefficients [k1, k2, k3, p1, p2]
DC = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

% Get distrotion coefficients
fx = K(1,1);
fy = K(2,2);
k1 = DC(1);
k2 = DC(2);
k3 = DC(3);
p1 = DC(4);
p2 = DC(5);

% Get image size
[ydim, xdim, bypixs] = size(image);

% Get the center of image
xc = xdim/2;
yc = ydim/2;

% Create X and Y coordinates grid
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:xdim, 1:ydim);

% Perform the cylindrical projection
theta = (X - xc) / fx;
h = (Y - yc) / fy;

% Cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian
xcap = sin(theta);
ycap = h;
zcap = cos(theta);

xyz_cap = cat(3, xcap, ycap, zcap);
xyz_cap = reshape(xyz_cap,[],3);

% Normalized coords
xyz_cap_norm = (K * xyz_cap')';
xn = xyz_cap_norm(:,1) ./ xyz_cap_norm(:,3);
yn = xyz_cap_norm(:,2) ./ xyz_cap_norm(:,3);

% Radial and tangential distortion 
r = xn.^2 + yn.^2;
xd_r = xn .* (1 + k1 * r.^2 + k2 * r.^4 + k3 * r.^6);
yd_r = yn .* (1 + k1 * r.^2 + k2 * r.^4 + k3 * r.^6);

xd_t = 2 * p1 * xn .* yn + p2 * (r.^2 + 2 * xn.^2);
yd_t = p1 * (r.^2 + 2 * yn.^2) + 2 * p2 * xn .* yn;

xd = xd_r + xd_t;
yd = yd_r + yd_t;

% Convert to 2D array
xd = reshape(ceil(xd),[ydim, xdim]);
yd = reshape(ceil(yd),[ydim, xdim]);

% Get projections
imageCylindrical = imwarp(image, cat(3,xd, yd), 'cubic');
imshow(imageCylindrical)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong using the imwarp function. Any help is appreciated!

Looks like you are projecting your image to one quarter of your intended surface.

xd and yd values span across the whole image. If I use the interp2 in MATLAB, it projects the image fine. I do not know what is going on with the imwarp function, though.

your expectation is not a cylinder, it's something else. your actual result looks cylindrical, except for the image just being filled in the top left quadrant. I think your expectations are wrong.

My expectation is a cylinder only; if my expectation is not a cylinder, then why do you think it is wrong?

nevermind then.
